# MongoDB Storing data from html or javascript

Tags: mongodb

Am new to MongoDB. What is the procedure in storing data from front end such as javascript to MongoDb and store its reference in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your Databases from Client-side Javascript directly (neither MongoDB nor PostgreSQL) - and in most cases, you really wouldn't want this. Client-side Code (be it Javascript or something else) can always be manipulated and the login data to your Database somehow has to be present there. Everyone who manipulates your Javascript or finds the login data could essentially do anything to your Database - manipulate things, add invalid data or simply delete anything.

What you'll need to do:

1. send the data to be stored to a Server-side Script (via POST or GET, Ajax or a Form-Submit depends on the exact use-case)
2. validate the data and use your Server-side programming Language (PHP, Python, Java, Node.js, Ruby, whatever...) to process and store it.
3. return the data needet by the Client to continue its work